# Reading Json Data From laravel controler

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-4

How do I read this json data and display in table in php Laravel?

```
[{"name":"G_edited"},{"name":"G_update"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `json_decode()` to get the desired results. Then use `foreach` to print in in a table. Consider this example:

```
<?php
$raw_json = '[{"name":"G_edited"},{"name":"G_update"}]';
$data = json_decode($raw_json, true);
?>

<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
    <tr><th>Name</th></tr>
    <?php foreach($data as $key => $value): ?>
        <tr><td><?php echo $value['name']; ?></td></tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = '[{"name":"G_edited"},{"name":"G_update"}]';
$array = json_decode($json);

foreach ($array as $item)
{
    echo $item['name'];
}
```